# Server strtotime incorrect

Tags: date, timezone, timestamp, localhost, strtotime

Both strtotime and mktime are outputting an incorrect timestamp and it's driving me mad.

If I add the following strtotime('2012-10-09');

I get 1349701200

Which is actually
Mon, 08 Oct 2012 13:00:00 GMT

I'm using my localhost, running MAMP. I'm assuming it's a server timezone issue, or something, but I don't understand why, or how to fix it.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strtotime uses default timezone to interpret the string. If you want different timezone you could specify it explicitly or change it for all calls:

```php
<?php

if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo  'date_default_timezone:  ' . date_default_timezone_get()."\n";
}

echo strtotime('2012-10-09')."\n"; # default timezone
echo strtotime('2012-10-09 UTC')."\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo strtotime('2012-10-09')."\n";
?>
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/b3Xpnr)

```php
date_default_timezone:  Europe/London
1349737200
1349740800
1349740800
```

POSIX timestamp counts number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 *UTC*. For example, midnight (00:00) in New York may be 20:00 in UTC at this time of year (the same POSIX timestamp). But 00:00 in UTC and 00:00 in New York correspond to different moments in time (different POSIX timestamps). Local clocks follow the Sun usually (roughly speaking) and even if it is night where you are; the Sun shines somewhere on Earth.

Comment: Sorry, actually just before I accept it...I don't think I fully understand why this is happening. Surely the number of seconds between two dates is exactly the same regardless of the timezone? The number of seconds between 1970/1/1 and 2012/10/9 is always the same isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelMallett: I've added explanation to the answer

Comment: Thanks again for that, i didnt realise the epoch was timezone based too